# Linking compute shader

Tags: c++, opengl, linker, compute-shader

I try to compile this small  [example](http://wili.cc/blog/entries/opengl-cs/ogl_cs_example.tar.gz) and I have this error executing the make:

```
g++ -o ogl_cs_example main.cpp opengl_cs.cpp opengl_util.cpp -Wall -Iinclude -lX11 -lGL -lGLU
/tmp/ccFLIOt2.o: In function `updateTex(int)':
main.cpp:(.text+0xc6): undefined reference to `glDispatchCompute'
/tmp/ccQ8pShN.o: In function `genTexture()':
opengl_util.cpp:(.text+0x3df): undefined reference to `glBindImageTexture'
/tmp/ccQ8pShN.o: In function `initGL()':
opengl_util.cpp:(.text+0x7dd): undefined reference to `glXCreateContextAttribsARB'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [example] Error 1
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Why not show some code?

Comment: The link in my question provides all the code. It's a small example from this [site](http://wili.cc/blog/opengl-cs.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those functions are all OpenGL / GLX extensions that are not provided by your platform's minimal implementation.

You have to load them at run-time using `glXGetProcAddress (...)`, they are not contained in any library that you link directly to. Though you can link to an extension managing library such as [GLEW](http://glew.sourceforge.net/) to do the dirty work for you, you will still have to do more than merely add a new linking dependency.

You generally have to initialize said libraries ***after*** you create your OpenGL render context. It is worth pointing out that one thing that sets WGL (Windows) and GLX (X11) apart is that you do not have to create a GL context before you can load extensions with GLX, so you can actually load `glXCreateContextAttribsARB`, `glDispatchCompute` and `glBindImageTexture` before you have a context. Whether the later two function pointers you get will do anything at run-time is a different story, however, and depends on the capabilities of the context you created.

Answer (score 0):

undefined reference means you did not LINK to the libraries

Comment: Yet I include OpenGL headers with this line `#include <GL/gl.h>` in opengl.h

Comment: No, he is missing the libraries.

Answer (score 0):

You are forgetting to link something. If you are using GLEW, make sure you are linking to glew32.lib (or libglew32.a or whatever for your system).